# Refresh query based on filter applied to ist table datasource

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have been dwelling with a problem for a couple of days and cannot find a solution, assuming that, what I am trying to achieve, is doable.
Basically, I have a table (let's called it Table1), which is created thru VBA every time the user makes a particular choice from the main menu. But this is not relevant to my issue so we can assume that it is a static table.
From Table1, I created several grouped queries, which group my data by different selected fields (by customer, by item, etc). These queries are also source data of several subforms included in my main form tabs.
Table1 is the only data that have posting date as field. The queries related to it don't, because they need to show only grouped data within the posting dates filtered on Table1 and not all the lines.
In my main form button, I have a working select sql statement which filters Table1 based on user input (date or date range). The problem is that I am not able to refresh the grouped queries with the filter input by the user and, therefore, the data displayed by the subforms. 
So may question is: is there a way to refresh queries based on filter input made on their main data source (in my case Table1) and then refresh the subform that use them as data source?

Thank you in advance.
Gianfranco

Comment: I see this is your first Question on Stack Overflow, welcome! Please provide some code so we can see what you have tried and better understand the context of your question, which in turn will help us out to help you. Also see [How To ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask better question which lead to better answers.

Comment: Hi Raymond, i don't know if adding code will help as right know it's the logic tha is missing. However, this is what I have so far: 
Dim Rst As DAO.Recordset
Set Rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM ValueEntryComb " _ 
  & "WHERE [Posting Date] Between # " & pubDateFrom & " # And # " & pubDateTo & " #;")
'ValueEntrComb is my main table
me.requery
me.recalc